# Remove values in a row from columns depending on same value in root column and columns with certain headers

Tags: excel, vba, header, row

I'm stuck with a Excel VBA problem and I hope someone here can help me with that.

I have a file with prices from different vendors in different columns. There is a root column (in my example file this is the column with the heading "TESLA"). I want the code to delete the prices only in the columns headed "FIAT" and "KIA" if they are in the same row as the price in the "TESLA" column and if they match the price in the "TESLA" column respectively.

So, in my example file, it should delete only the value 36,00 and the value 88,00 in the column "FIAT". In the column "KIA" only the value 56,00 and the value 896,00.

The values in the other columns should be kept, even if they match the value in the "TESLA" column.

Here's what I've got so far:

```
Sub delete_matches()

    Dim LastRow as long
    Dim LastColumn As Long, i As Long, Position As Long

    With Sheets("Sheet1")
        LastColumn = .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
        LastRow = .Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        For i = LastColumn To 1 Step -1

            Position = InStr(1, .Cells(1, i), "TESLA")

            If Position <> 0 Then
   

  'Here has to happen something..
           


            End If

        Next i

    End With
    
End Sub
```

Comment: Please do not include links to your google drive in your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First identifying the location of the key columns  (TESA,KIA,FIAT), then compare and clean the data.

```vb
Sub delete_matches()
    Dim LastRow As Long
    Dim LastColumn As Long, i As Long
    Dim tCol As Integer, kCol As Integer, fCol As Integer
    With Sheets("Sheet1")
        arr = .UsedRange.Value
        For i = 1 To UBound(arr, 2)
            If Trim(arr(1, i)) = "TESLA" Then tCol = i
            If Trim(arr(1, i)) = "KIA" Then kCol = i
            If Trim(arr(1, i)) = "FIAT" Then fCol = i
        Next i
        If tCol * kCol * fCol = 0 Then
            MsgBox "Can't find key column header"
        Else
            For i = 1 To UBound(arr)
                If arr(i, kCol) = arr(i, tCol) Then arr(i, kCol) = ""
                If arr(i, fCol) = arr(i, tCol) Then arr(i, fCol) = ""
            Next i
        End If
        .UsedRange.Value = arr
    End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

This can also be accomplished using Power Query, available in Windows Excel 2010+ and Excel 365 (Windows or Mac)

To use Power Query

- Select some cell in your Data Table
- `Data => Get&Transform => from Table/Range` or `from within sheet`
- When the PQ Editor opens: `Home => Advanced Editor`
- Make note of the Table **Name** in Line 2
- Paste the M Code below in place of what you see
- Change the Table name in line 2 back to what was generated originally.
- Read the comments and explore the `Applied Steps` to understand the algorithm

```
let

//Change next line to reflect actual data source
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],

//Transformation list can be created in many ways, but should result in what is shown here
    #"Remove Matchings" = Table.FromRecords(Table.TransformRows(#"Source",
    (r) => Record.TransformFields(r,{
        {"FIAT", each if r[TESLA]= _ then null else _},
        {"KIA", each if r[TESLA] = _ then null else _}
        }))),

//Setting data types is a good idea in Power Query
//I've "assumed" the values are of a Currency.Type, but there are other possibilities
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Remove Matchings",{
        {"item no", Int64.Type}, {"description", type text}, {"quantity", Int64.Type}} &
        List.Transform(List.RemoveFirstN(Table.ColumnNames(Source),3), each {_, Currency.Type}))    
    
in
    #"Changed Type"
```

[image]